# determine the $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 $ such that $x^2 -5y^2$ divides both $x+y$ and $2y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the following set:

$$
S\quad := \quad 
\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \ : \  x^2 -5y^2 \ | \ \text{gcd}(x+y,2y) \}.
$$

I wonder if there is an elementary way to describe it more explicitly. I am familiar with elementary number theory, group theory quadratic reciprocity. I hope that is sufficient to give a more explicit description.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

Note that a the $\text{gcd}(x+y,2y)$ can be replaced by $\text{gcd}(x+y,2x)$
or $\text{gcd}(x-y,2y)$. the expression $x^2-5y^2$ is invariant under the replacements $x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto -y$.
The divisibility conditions are also unvariant under this replacements. For this reason we can restrict our attention to 
$(x,y) \in {\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}^2$.
If $x=0$ we have no solutions. If $y=0$ we only find the solutions $x= \pm 1$.
Now we assume that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to Pell's equation are the only solutions. For suppose $x^2-5y^2=d$; note that $d\not\equiv 2\mod{4}$. Then $d\mid x+y$ and $d\mid 2y$.

If $d$ is odd, then $d\mid y$, so that $d\mid x$ as well and then $d^2\mid x^2-5y^2$, so that $d = \pm 1$.

Otherwise, $d$ is even, in which case $d\mid 2y$ implies $\frac{d}{2}\mid y$. From $d\mid x+y$ we can then conclude that $\frac{d}{2}\mid x$, so that $\frac{d^2}{4} \mid x^2-5y^2=d$. Then we must have $d=4$. But this is impossible: since $x$ and $y$ must both be even, writing $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$ gives $x_1^2-5y_1^2=1$, $2\mid x_1+y_1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Dear @rogerl, thank you for your input! I have a question for you.
How does $\frac{d^2}{4} \ | \ d$ imply that 
$d=4$? I would say that we might as well have that $d=2$ under these circonstances.

Comment: Since $\frac{d^2}{4}\mid d$, we must have $\frac{d^2}{4}\le d$ as well, so that $d = 0$, $2$, or $4$. $0$ is impossible since $xy>0$, while $d=2$ is impossible since as noted above $d\not\equiv 2\mod{4}$.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. If I understand you correctly, you also call 
$x^2 - 5y^2 = -1$ the Pell-equation?

Comment: Yes, see @SDolan's answer elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite families of solutions can be obtained from solutions to Pell's equation. For example, solutions of $  x^2 -5y^2=1$ or $ -1 $ generated from $x=2,y=1$ will all automatically be in $S$:-

$$(2,1),(9,4), (38,17), ...$$